# How can I save images with laravel and access them from another laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, image, phpmyadmin, laravel-5.8

I have two laravel 5.8 projects.

In one project I'm saving files, (such as images and pdf), in the `public/uploads/files` directory.

Now, I want to access those files from the other project.

How can I do that?

I'm working with laravel 5.8 and phpMyAdmin.

Comment: when you say you want to access that file in your second project do you mean you want to access it as if they belong completely in the second project ? if it's the case you can just access them by providing the URL of each image in the second project and for that the first and the second project must be accessible otherwise you can copy that file in the second project

Comment: thanks for your answer it was so helpfull and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to visit the files in project b, use the source url of project a will be fine. Maybe you want project b have the same permissions of files like project a, there's different ways:

1. use the symbolic link
2. real-time sync(like inotify + rsync)

Comment: thanks for you answer, I just used the url of the other project and it wirked very well.